# How to fix Ubuntu calculator malfunction?

Tags: gnome-calculator

Today, 8 February 2020, I open the calculator to use, but what I found is that the calculator has no button like this.

[image]

I don't know why it became like this. Three days ago, I was using it and there were no problems. I am sure that I didn't do anything harmful to the system. This happens on both my laptop and desktop pc.

I am using Ubuntu 19.10. Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: @archismanPanigrahi It is a snap version.

Comment: Hi, @ArchismanPanigrahi It is fixed now. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the issue happened in both your laptop and desktop, it may be due to automatic update of the snap version of gnome-calculator. Use the following command to shift to the apt version.

`sudo snap remove gnome-calculator && sudo apt install gnome-calculator`

Comment: Hi, Archisman, I am wondering if I can fix the calculator for snap version. I am finding out a solution to fix the snap-version calculator. I tried reinstalling it, but it doesn't work. Do you have any solutions to this?

Comment: I don't know, but if it has not been fixed yet, you can report a bug here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-calculator/+bugs?field.tag=snap